# Coded UI Test for DevExpress Controls does not work

Tags: winforms, devexpress, coded-ui-tests, devexpress-windows-ui

I am going to start work on new project in which i am using DevExpress controls with winform applicaiton.

I want to do **Coded UI test for winforms application and DevExpress controls.**
I have VS 2010 Ultimate and DevExpress Controls 12.2 version(latest version).

In one of my example, i have created winform with GridControl of DevExpress.XtraGrid. when i create Coded UI test for this Grid Control, It's not working.
I mean it does not support it.

Can anyone give me solution/example/tutorial to do Coded UI for DevExpress controls in winforms.
Thanks !!

Comment: Which scenario you've tested and what the exactly does not work? How does it related to `devexpress-windows-ui` tag? Have you registered a corresponding bug report in [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center)?

Comment: What error do you get? Keep in mind that expired trial version stops support Coded-UI.

Comment: Hi, Code UI Test Builder suddenly gets crashed with Unhandled JIT exception when it is trying to retrieve the properties from the identified 'Wait Indicator' DevEx control.

Comment: Please help how to retrieve/capture properties for Wait Indicator DevEx control using Coded UI Test Builder

Answer (score 1):

Refer: [DevExpress Releases DXperience 12.1 with Coded UI Support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/08/devexpress-releases-dxperience-12-1-with-coded-ui-support.aspx) and [this](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/coded-ui/).

Here you will get few videos that help you to understand about grid control and others also.

> You can also go through [Coded UI Test Extension for 3rd party
>   controls - the basics explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/10/28/coded-ui-test-extension-for-3rd-party-controls-the-basics-explained.aspx) article of MSDN and documentation [Verifying Code by Using Coded User Interface Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726%28v=vs.110%29).

More References:
[DevExpress 2012 GridControl Coded-ui-tests issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032879/devexpress-2012-gridcontrol-coded-ui-tests-issue)

Comment: i have already read all these articles.but i don't get any complete tutorials/videos.the videos posted here are .swf files with no description for DxGrid controls in Coded UI Test

Answer (score 1):

Ok for starters, ditch VS2010 and upgrade to VS2013 (Including latest update). If you don't do this - stop reading.

Next thing is **versioning**

To get reliable record and playback you will need to have the exact same version of DevExpess installed on your VS2013 Premium development box that your application under test uses.

So for example, if your app under test uses DevExpress 14.1.8 - INSTALL THAT VERSION in your coded ui dev environment. If you don't get the versioning exactly right - then it simply won't work.

Once you have that setup, create a new coded ui test project, and you should automatically get a DevExpress coded ui extension dll added.

Now fire up your application under test. Inside Visual Studio you will most likely get a sample test method, after creating the project. Set focus somewhere inside the test method, and then start the coded ui recorder. Now you should be able to identify controls and interact with them using the recorder. Save your actions / control identifications off to the UI map using the Generate Code in the recorder.

This should give you a good place to start with. If you really want my help, then you can send me a PM and I can share a lot of information that is beyond the scope of this. I'm on skype too and have made a lot of progress in the time I've spent specifically testing DevExpress based WinForms.

I can also share with you some helpful wrapped controls that wrap stuff like DXGrid to make your life tons easier.